# Left arrow key not working after spill, even with Karabiner?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, keybindings

I'm on a Macbook Pro 13 (mid-12, not retina), macOS High Sierra. I spilled a few droplets of water (actual water) and my **left arrow** key decided to stop working. That's fair. Then I thought i don't use the **right-alt** key, so I tried to remap it using Karabiner-Elements. It didn't work (it was still registering as alt). BUT when I remap it to the **right arrow** key, it works!! I honestly don't know why that's the case. So I thought it could be a software issue, restarting the computer, and going into another user account (that's newly made) didn't help.

Oh and trying other keys also doesn't work. And I also tried an hidutil command and that didn't work. So I don't think the problem is from Karabiner.

So is there a reason why "softwarely" remapping the key wouldn't work?

Comment: I found more than once that WHEN remapping (e.g.) "left_arrow" directly to another key did NOT work a line like: __ >"to": [ { "shell_command": "osascript -e  'tell application \"System Events\" to key code 123'" } ] < __ in a Karabiner manipulator (or an Applescript, btw.) DID work. "123" is Apple's internal key code for "left arrow"…